# ORA-01861: the value does not match the format string

Tags: sql, oracle, validation

I have this External Table:

```
CREATE TABLE PFun ( 
  idF   VARCHAR(255),
  dt   DATE
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (
    TYPE oracle_loader
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_dep    
  ACCESS PARAMETERS
  ( 
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY '\n' 
    BADFILE     CHARACTER
      DISCARDFILE CHARACTER
      LOGFILE     CHARACTER
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
      OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "'"
      MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL     
      (
        idF     CHAR(255),
        dt      CHAR(255) date_format DATE mask 'YYYY/MM/DD'
      )  
  )
  LOCATION ('prfun.csv')
)
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

**I created this function to return the week number of the year**

```
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TestFunction(dtIn IN DATE)  
RETURN NUMBER   
IS res NUMBER;
BEGIN  
    SELECT CEIL((TO_DATE(dtIn, 'yyyy/mm/dd') - TO_DATE('2020/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))/7)
    INTO res
    FROM PFun
    WHERE dtIn >= '2020-01-01';
    RETURN res;
END;
/
SELECT idF, TestFunction(dt)
FROM PFun;
```

If I only run the function it tells me that everything has been compiled. **But** when i run the SELECT it gives me the following error:

```
ORA-29913: Error executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-01861: the value does not match the format string
ORA-06512: a "SYSTEM.TESTFUNCTION", line 5
29913.0000 - "error in executing% s callout"
* Cause: The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
* Action: Examine the error messages take appropriate action.
```

[I enter the dates like this: '2020/01/01' but sql-developer on the control query shows them to me like this '01-JAN-20'. *I don't know if this info is important*]

***How I fix that?***

Comment: are you able to execute `select * from PFun`?

Comment: yes I can do it and it shows me all the data

Comment: Try ` WHERE dtIn >= TO_DATE('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') `

Comment: **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting a date field into again date which seems to be throwing an error.

Also, You are trying to compare `date` field `dtIn` with `string`. The `string` should be converted to `date` before comparing with the date filed (`dtIn >= '2020-01-01'`)

Try the following query in your function:

```
SELECT CEIL(dtIn - TO_DATE('2020/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))/7) -- to_Date is not needed for dtIn
    INTO res
    FROM PFun
    WHERE dtIn >= date '2020-01-01' -- this should be date so made it date using date literal
```

Comment: is telling me this now: ORA-29913: Error executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-01422: **Exact extraction shows more lines than required**
ORA-06512: a "SYSTEM.TESTFUNCTION", line 5
29913.0000 - "error in executing% s callout"
* Cause: The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
* Action: Examine the error messages take appropriate action.

Comment: Your select query is returning more than one record. try to use exact where condition so that it returns only one record `INTO res`.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic that you want to achieve using this function?

Comment: it's just an exercise, however thanks for the solution, everything works now

Answer (score 0):

Just use `TO_CHAR( your_date, 'WW' )` to return the week number:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION TestFunction(dtIn IN DATE) RETURN NUMBER   
IS
BEGIN  
    RETURN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dtIn, 'WW'));
END;
/
```

*(And you probably don't need to write a function for something that simple and could just use `TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(your_column, 'WW'))` in place of the function call.)*

Then, for this year:

```sql
SELECT DATE '2019-12-31' + LEVEL AS dtIn,
       TestFunction( DATE '2019-12-31' + LEVEL ) AS week_num
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 366
```

It will output:

> ```
> DTIN      | WEEK_NUM
> :-------- | -------:
> 01-JAN-20 |        1
> 02-JAN-20 |        1
> 03-JAN-20 |        1
> 04-JAN-20 |        1
> 05-JAN-20 |        1
> 06-JAN-20 |        1
> 07-JAN-20 |        1
> 08-JAN-20 |        2
> 09-JAN-20 |        2
> ...
> 21-DEC-20 |       51
> 22-DEC-20 |       51
> 23-DEC-20 |       52
> 24-DEC-20 |       52
> 25-DEC-20 |       52
> 26-DEC-20 |       52
> 27-DEC-20 |       52
> 28-DEC-20 |       52
> 29-DEC-20 |       52
> 30-DEC-20 |       53
> 31-DEC-20 |       53
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e4bd4e9430251074633f22d01f1cfa9c)*